# Django: How to use custom slug in gereric DetailView (Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug)

Tags: python, django, generics

> I am newbie on python django. when following [Django Tutorial > Part04 > Generic View](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/) , i have trouble with using `Detail View`. and actually its my first question on StackOverflow, so if i am wrong with something, please let me know. Thanks very much.

#### What I Want?

- i think `url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail")` is better than `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail")`. because its more readable and intuitive.
- so i do not want to change `polls/urls.py`.
- how can i use Detail View, but remain `<CUSTOM_SLUG>` on `views.py`

#### Source Code

`django_project/polls/urls.py` ( currently not working )

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name="results"),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    )
```

`django_project/polls/urls.py` ( working source, but i don't want this. )

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.IndexView.as_view(), name="index"),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/results/$', views.results, name="results"),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/vote/$', views.vote, name="vote"),
    )
```

`django_project/polls/views.py`

```
class DetailView(generic.DetailView):
  model = Question
  template_name = "polls/detail.html"
```

#### Error Message

Generic detail view DetailView must be called with either an object pk or a slug.

Comment: i found out one solution. when i add `pk_url_kwarg = "question_id"`, it works!!! ( from https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.pk_url_kwarg )

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial04/

> The DetailView generic view expects the primary key value captured from the URL to be called "pk", so we’ve changed poll_id to pk for the generic views.

so this will obviously not work:

```
url(r'^(?P<question_id>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

whereas this will work:

```
url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetailView.as_view(), name="detail"),
```

#### subclassing `DetailView` to use a different regex group name:

https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/detail.py

But if you subclass `DetailView` you can tell it what is the `pk` parameter:

```
class MyCustomDetailView(DetailView):
    pk_url_kwarg = 'object_id'
```

`pk` is a standard term in django; while this may make your code more readable to you,
anybody else comfortable with django may think `pk` is more readable. What is the point of using a `generic` view if you want to customize all the small details?